# Python discord bot error via subprocess library

Tags: python, discord

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'comunicate'
```

Comment: Do you have a question? If you do, please post a [mcve] as well.

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'comunicate'`

It looks like you're trying to call [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) but you've got a typo.

Comment: trying to use subprocess library

Comment: @Arlecchino I understand, but right now you've got a typo in a method call and it's causing an ArrtibuteError to be thrown, since the attribute you're trying to access doesn't exist. Fix the typo and update this to reflect other errors if they come up.